# How to search for files containing specific word?

Tags: command-line

How to search for files containing specific word?

Comment: Do you actually mean search file NAMES containing with a specific word in them?   ie: all files that have the term FUN in their names, , FUN_time.txt FUN_stuff.txt Or search INSIDE a file for specific words?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

With command line you have several options. The 3 I use the most are...

1. `locate {part_of_word}`

   This assumes your locate-database is up to date but you can update this manually with: `sudo updatedb`
2. `grep` as explained by dr_willis.
   One remark: `-R` after `grep` also searched within directories.
   Example:

   ```
   cd\
   grep -R {something_to_look_for} {where_to_look_in}
   ```
3. `find . -name '*{part_of_word}*' -print`

Where `.` is the directory where you are at the moment and `*` is a wildcard.

Oh and you can also combine these. Example: 
`locate {something}|grep {some_part_of_something}|more`

If I recall correctly: `locate` is the fastest one (assuming your database is up to date) and `find` is the slowest one. And `grep` is the most complex but also the most versatile one of these since you can use regexes.

Answer (score 32):

grep -R "what" "where"

example:

`grep -R hello /home`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `grep` to list the files containing `word` in the given `directory`:

```
grep -Ril word directory
```

Here:
* `-R` recursively search files in sub-directories.
* `-i` ignore text case
* `-l` show file names instead of file contents portions. (note: `-L` shows file names that do not contain the word).

use `man grep` to get all the options

Comment: Just so you know: `-i` performs a case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 5):

The grep command is commonly used for this.

grep PATTERN filename

and grep can do some very complex searching.

```
willis@Cow:~$ grep --help
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.
PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).
Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c
```

Comment: or you can do "rgrep word ." to recursively search every file and subdirectory for "word"